# Regular expression to remove all the &nbsp; that is coming before and after <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen references in this site. But I have this problem that is particular to my code. 
I have some variable like

```
viewSourceText = "koushik&nbsp;↵<div id="okokoko">some value </div>&nbsp;"
```

now i want to remove "&nbsp" appearing before and after the  tag.So that output would be like this:

```
 viewSourceText = "koushik<div id="okokoko">some value </div>"
```

now my code sample is:

```
viewSourceText.replace(/&nbsp;\n<div/g, "<div>");
viewSourceText.replace(/</div>&nbsp;/g, "</div>");
```

But not working properly.

Comment: add the m modifier in your regex to look at multilines: /gm. also, replacing "&nbsp;<div" with "<div>" would give you "<div>>"

Comment: And once again the warning: [Don't use regular rxpressions to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la). Since you are using JavaScript anyway, why not the the DOM to find and remove the non-breaking spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Here the proper way to do it in the DOM without regular expressions:

```
function removeNbspAroundDivs (start) {
    var divs = start.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        var element = div;
        while ((element = element.previousSibling) && element.nodeType == 3) {
            element.nodeValue = element.nodeValue.replace(/[\u00A0\n]+$/, "");
            if (element.nodeValue.length > 0) break;
        }
        var element = div;
        while ((element = element.nextSibling) && element.nodeType == 3) {
            element.nodeValue = element.nodeValue.replace(/^[\u00A0\n]+/, "");
            if (element.nodeValue.length > 0) break;
        }
    }
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bH95J/)